# How to customize scrollbar with Jquery chosen

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to customize my scrollbar on a dropbox with chosen , i want to change the thumb color.

I tried looking for the class name on the chosen.css, but there is no such thing named Thumb or scrollbarvertical or etc.

Where can i modify my scrollbar?

Comment: Keep in mind modifying your scrollbar will not have the same result in all browsers.

Comment: Which means i have to add moz, etc , right?

Comment: No, what you are trying to do is not supported in all browsers see here: http://caniuse.com/#search=scrollbars. Firefox doesn't support it so a browser specific prefix won't help in this case. See also: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scrollbar.

Comment: Ah ok, this makes me think twice about it then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...for customize vertical scrollbars try this example: http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-webkit-vertical-scrollbars/